# Improving the efficiency of multiple nested for loops in R

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I am relatively new to R. I have created code to review a dataframe and identify rows of data based on specific conditions, and mark those rows with a 1 and the column "check". The code works exactly how I have intended it to with the test data. My problem is the real dataset is 1 million plus rows, and while it works, it is way too slow. I would appreciate help in improving the efficiency of this code.

```
#create test data
alarm <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
setpoint <- c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,8,8,9,8,8,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,8,10,10,8,10,10,10)

temp <- data.frame(alarm, setpoint)

#create a new column to capture if there is any changes to setpoint after any alarm 
temp$check <- ""

#review everyrow in dataframe
for(i in 1:nrow(temp)){
  cat(round(i/nrow(temp)*100,2),"%    \r") # prints the percentage complete in realtime.
  if(temp$alarm[i]==1 && temp$setpoint[i] >= 10){
    #for when alarm has occurred and the setpoint is 10 or above review the next 5 rows
    for(j in 0:5){ 
      if(temp$setpoint[i] != temp$setpoint[i+j]){
        #for when there has been a change in the setpoint
        for(j in 0:10){
          if(temp$setpoint[i] != temp$setpoint[i+j]){
            temp$check[i+j]<-'1'
            if(temp$setpoint[i+j] != (temp$setpoint[i+j+1])){break}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

> print(temp)
   alarm setpoint check
1      0       10      
2      0       10      
3      0       10      
4      0       10      
5      0       10      
6      0       10      
7      1       10      
8      1       10      
9      0        8     1
10     0        8     1
11     0        9      
12     0        8      
13     0        8      
14     0       10      
15     0       10      
16     0       10      
17     1       10      
18     0       10      
19     0       10      
20     0       10      
21     0       10      
22     1       10      
23     0       10      
24     0       10      
25     0        8     1
26     0       10      
27     0       10      
28     0        8      
29     0       10      
30     0       10      
31     0       10
```

Answer (score 11):

Looking for efficiency, as the loops are already written, you could use `Rcpp`.

`C++` syntax isn't very far away from `R` syntax, main changes are :

- declare variables
- index vectors from 0 on
- rename the third inner loop counter from `j` to `k` because although keeping `j` works in `R` it's quite error prone and not working in `C++`, as second inner loop will be overwritten
- check more strictly that `i+j` or `i+k` never go above total number of rows

This leads to `check_data.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame check_data(DataFrame df) {
  NumericVector alarm = df["alarm"];
  NumericVector setpoint = df["setpoint"];
  int n = alarm.size();
  LogicalVector check(n);
  int i,j,k;
  
  for(i=0; i<n;i++){
     if(alarm[i]==1 && setpoint[i] >= 10){
       Rcout << "pct = " << i*100/n << "%" << std::endl; // prints the percentage complete in realtime.
       //for when alarm has occured and the setpoint is 10 or above review the next 5 rows
       for(j=1; j<5; j++){ 
          if (i+j > n-1) break;
         if(setpoint[i] != setpoint[i+j]){
            //for when there has been a change in the setpoint
           for(k=1; k<10;k++){
             if (i+k> n-1) break;
             if(setpoint[i] != setpoint[i+k]){
               check[i+k] = true;
               if (i+k+1> n-1) break;
               if(setpoint[i+k] != (setpoint[i+k+1])){break;}
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
  
  df["check"]=check;
  return(df);
}


// You can include R code blocks in C++ files processed with sourceCpp
// (useful for testing and development). The R code will be automatically 
// run after the compilation.
//

/*** R
alarm <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
setpoint <- c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,8,8,9,8,8,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,8,10,10,8,10,10,10)

temp <- data.frame(alarm, setpoint)

check_data(temp)
*/
```

You can then make `check_data` function available in your R environment by running :

```
library(Rcpp)

sourceCpp('check_data.cpp')

check_data(temp)
pct = 19%
pct = 22%
pct = 51%
pct = 67%

   alarm setpoint check
1      0       10 FALSE
2      0       10 FALSE
3      0       10 FALSE
4      0       10 FALSE
5      0       10 FALSE
6      0       10 FALSE
7      1       10 FALSE
8      1       10 FALSE
9      0        8  TRUE
10     0        8  TRUE
11     0        9 FALSE
12     0        8 FALSE
13     0        8 FALSE
14     0       10 FALSE
15     0       10 FALSE
16     0       10 FALSE
17     1       10 FALSE
18     0       10 FALSE
19     0       10 FALSE
20     0       10 FALSE
21     0       10 FALSE
22     1       10 FALSE
23     0       10 FALSE
24     0       10 FALSE
25     0        8  TRUE
26     0       10 FALSE
27     0       10 FALSE
28     0        8 FALSE
29     0       10 FALSE
30     0       10 FALSE
31     0       10 FALSE
```

**Performance comparison:**

```
Unit: microseconds
 expr     min      lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
  ref 13051.8 16832.4 18510.316 18448.95 19930.10 28335.9   100
 Rcpp    68.3   108.7   179.845   168.60   236.85   515.1   100
```

Comment: Minor point but you could probably just change ``std::end`` to ``\n`` as there isn't a need to flush the buffer after every loop iterations and it might incur a small performance hit.

Answer (score 9):

If I understand your objective properly, perhaps you can try the `data.table` approach like below

```
library(data.table)
setDT(temp)[
    ,
    check := +({
        d <- cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(setpoint)) != 0) == 1
        d & min(c(which(d), Inf)) <= 5
    }),
    cumsum(alarm == 1 & setpoint >= 10)
]
```

which gives

```
    alarm setpoint check
 1:     0       10     0
 2:     0       10     0
 3:     0       10     0
 4:     0       10     0
 5:     0       10     0
 6:     0       10     0
 7:     1       10     0
 8:     1       10     0
 9:     0        8     1
10:     0        8     1
11:     0        9     0
12:     0        8     0
13:     0        8     0
14:     0       10     0
15:     0       10     0
16:     0       10     0
17:     1       10     0
18:     0       10     0
19:     0       10     0
20:     0       10     0
21:     0       10     0
22:     1       10     0
23:     0       10     0
24:     0       10     0
25:     0        8     1
26:     0       10     0
27:     0       10     0
28:     0        8     0
29:     0       10     0
30:     0       10     0
31:     0       10     0
```

Comment: Is there a reason for the leading `+` outside of the parentheses here: `check := +({` ? Great answer, I've been unaware of `diff()`'s existence for years!

Comment: @MattSummersgill `+` turns boolean values to numerical.

Answer (score 6):

It is straightforward to do this with a `dplyr` pipe. I've not tested the speed, but it will certainly be much faster than your approach...

```
library(dplyr)

alarm <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
setpoint <- c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,8,8,9,8,8,10,10,10,10,10,
              10,10,10,10,10,10,8,10,10,8,10,10,10)

temp <- data.frame(alarm, setpoint)

temp %>% 
  mutate(grp = cumsum(alarm == 1 & setpoint >=10)) %>%   #set grouping variable
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(check = as.numeric((cumsum(c(0, diff(setpoint)) != 0) == 1) &
                            (row_number() <= 5))) %>%    #see note
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-grp)                                           #remove grouping variable

  alarm setpoint check
   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0       10     0
 2     0       10     0
 3     0       10     0
 4     0       10     0
 5     0       10     0
 6     0       10     0
 7     1       10     0
 8     1       10     0
 9     0        8     1
10     0        8     1
11     0        9     0
12     0        8     0
13     0        8     0
14     0       10     0
15     0       10     0
16     0       10     0
17     1       10     0
18     0       10     0
19     0       10     0
20     0       10     0
21     0       10     0
22     1       10     0
23     0       10     0
24     0       10     0
25     0        8     1
26     0       10     0
27     0       10     0
28     0        8     0
29     0       10     0
30     0       10     0
31     0       10     0
```

Note - this line uses `diff` to check for changes in `setpoint` within each group (padding it with a zero to keep the lengths the same), and sets `check` to identify the items after the first change and before the second, provided they are within the first five rows of that group. The `as.numeric` changes it from logical to numeric (0/1), which is closer to what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

### Edit:

This answer provides the correct answer with the example dataset but not with @Luke_DataSci's actual dataset.

---

### Original answer:

Here is a potential 'brute force' solution that should be significantly faster:

```r
library(dplyr)

alarm <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
setpoint <- c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,8,8,8,8,8,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,8,10,10,8,10,10,10)
test_dataset_1 <- data.frame(alarm, setpoint)

alarm2 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
setpoint2 <- c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,8,8,9,8,8,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,8,10,10,8,10,10,10)
test_dataset_2 <- data.frame(alarm2, setpoint2)

ifelse_func <- function(df){
df$check <- ifelse(
  (lag(df$alarm, n = 1, default = 0) == 1 &
     lag(df$setpoint, n = 1, default = 0) >= 10 &
     df$setpoint != 10) |
    (lag(df$alarm, n = 2, default = 0) == 1 &
       lag(df$setpoint, n = 2, default = 0) >= 10 &
       df$setpoint != 10 &
       df$setpoint == lag(df$setpoint, n = 1, default = 0)) |
    (lag(df$alarm, n = 3, default = 0) == 1 &
       lag(df$setpoint, n = 3, default = 0) >= 10 &
       df$setpoint != 10 &
       (df$setpoint == lag(df$setpoint, n = 1, default = 0) |
          lag(df$setpoint, n = 1, default = 0) == 10) &
       (df$setpoint == lag(df$setpoint, n = 2, default = 0) |
          lag(df$setpoint, n = 2, default = 0) == 10)) |
    (lag(df$alarm, n = 4, default = 0) == 1 &
       lag(df$setpoint, n = 4, default = 0) >= 10 &
       df$setpoint != 10 &
       (df$setpoint == lag(df$setpoint, n = 1, default = 0) |
       lag(df$setpoint, n = 1, default = 0) == 10) &
       (df$setpoint == lag(df$setpoint, n = 2, default = 0) |
          lag(df$setpoint, n = 2, default = 0) == 10) &
       (df$setpoint == lag(df$setpoint, n = 3, default = 0) |
          lag(df$setpoint, n = 3, default = 0) == 10)) |
    (lag(df$alarm, n = 5, default = 0) == 1 &
       lag(df$setpoint, n = 5, default = 0) >= 10 &
       df$setpoint != 10 &
       (df$setpoint == lag(df$setpoint, n = 1, default = 0) |
          lag(df$setpoint, n = 1, default = 0) == 10) &
       (df$setpoint == lag(df$setpoint, n = 2, default = 0) |
          lag(df$setpoint, n = 2, default = 0) == 10) &
       (df$setpoint == lag(df$setpoint, n = 3, default = 0) |
          lag(df$setpoint, n = 3, default = 0) == 10) &
       (df$setpoint == lag(df$setpoint, n = 4, default = 0) |
          lag(df$setpoint, n = 4, default = 0) == 10)),
  1, "")
return(df)
}

forloop_func <- function(df){
  df$check <- ""
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    #  cat(round(i/nrow(temp)*100,2),"%    \r") # prints the percentage complete in realtime.
    if(df$alarm[i]==1 && df$setpoint[i] >= 10){
      #for when alarm has occurred and the setpoint is 10 or above review the next 5 rows
      for(j in 0:5){ 
        if(df$setpoint[i] != df$setpoint[i+j]){
          #for when there has been a change in the setpoint
          for(j in 0:10){
            if(df$setpoint[i] != df$setpoint[i+j]){
              df$check[i+j]<-'1'
              if(df$setpoint[i+j] != (df$setpoint[i+j+1])){break}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return(df)
}

all_equal(ifelse_func(test_dataset_1), forloop_func(test_dataset_1))
#> [1] TRUE
all_equal(ifelse_func(test_dataset_2), forloop_func(test_dataset_2))
#> [1] TRUE

library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)
res <- microbenchmark(ifelse_func(test_dataset_2),
                      forloop_func(test_dataset_2),
                      times = 10)
autoplot(res) + ggtitle("Time difference for 31 rows")
#> Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
```

[image]

```r
set.seed(123)
temp2 <- data.frame(alarm = sample(alarm, 1000, replace = TRUE),
                    setpoint = sample(setpoint, 1000, replace = TRUE))
res2 <- microbenchmark(ifelse_func(temp2), forloop_func(temp2), times = 10)
autoplot(res2) + ggtitle("Time difference for 1,000 rows")
#> Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
```

[image]

```r
temp3 <- data.frame(alarm = sample(alarm, 10000, replace = TRUE),
                    setpoint = sample(setpoint, 10000, replace = TRUE))
res3 <- microbenchmark(ifelse_func(temp3), forloop_func(temp3), times = 10)
autoplot(res3) + ggtitle("Time difference for 10,000 rows")
#> Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
```

[image]

```r
temp4 <- data.frame(alarm = sample(alarm, 100000, replace = TRUE),
                    setpoint = sample(setpoint, 100000, replace = TRUE))
res4 <- microbenchmark(ifelse_func(temp4), forloop_func(temp4), times = 6)
autoplot(res4) + ggtitle("Time difference for 100,000 rows")
#> Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
```

[image]

---

For 1 millions rows:

```r
temp5 <- data.frame(alarm = sample(alarm, 1000000, replace = TRUE),
                    setpoint = sample(setpoint, 1000000, replace = TRUE))

Unit: milliseconds
                expr         min          lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
  ifelse_func(temp5)    873.8556    873.8556   1181.997   1181.997   1490.138   1490.138     2  a
 forloop_func(temp5) 292242.7181 292242.7181 295101.463 295101.463 297960.208 297960.208     2   b
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

So, despite being ~3X slower than your for-loop method with 31 rows, this approach is ~250X faster with 1 million rows.

Now the question is whether or not it provides the correct answer...

Comment: Hey Jared, your code is a lot faster, but I am not sure if it takes into consideration this line of code "if(temp$setpoint[i+j] != (temp$setpoint[i+j+1])){break}", which breaks the 0:10 loop if there is a change in the setpoint. If I change the test data to setpoint <- c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,8,8,9,8,8,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,8,10,10,8,10,10,10), you will see the difference.

Comment: Yes, I see; are you able to please edit your question to include a second example dataset (one that contains `setpoint <- c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,8,8,9,8,8,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,8,10,10,8,10,10,10)`) with the expected outcome?

Comment: I've edited my answer and I think I've fixed the problem, but now I am concerned there may be other issues; please check that you get the same output as your 'for loops' method on some of your actual data and if you can find any other examples that 'break' my ifelse method I'll update it again

Comment: When I attempt to use your updated code with my large date set, it is selecting the 5 rows after each alarm, regardless of if there has been a change in the setpoint. The other concern I have and should have mentioned this earlier, it could become difficult if I wanted to change the looping values (e.g. the 5 and 10 values).

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate the logic of your algorithm. You spend a lot of time in needless looping redoing steps that were already performed (or made an error in the implementation).

I'll comment in your code

```
for(i in 1:nrow(temp)){
  cat(round(i/nrow(temp)*100,2),"%    \r") # prints the percentage complete in realtime.
```

printing is ok - but usually really slows things down. If you have to do consider putting it in a `if (i %% 100)` so it will print only every 100th line (or whatever you choose).

```
  if(temp$alarm[i]==1 && temp$setpoint[i] >= 10){
```

ok - but could be vectorized (will run MUCH faster) outside the loop into `temp$cond <- temp$alarm==1 & temp$setpoint >= 10`

```
    for(j in 0:5){
```

**for both loops the condition is NEVER true for j = 0** - so start j at 1

```
      if(temp$setpoint[i] != temp$setpoint[i+j]){
        for(j in 0:10){
```

first: don't reuse `j`!
Here you don't need to start j at 0 - **just 2 lines above you found where it is different!** you checked it. Just start at j and skip the `if(temp$setpoint[i]...`.

```
          if(temp$setpoint[i] != temp$setpoint[i+j]){
            temp$check[i+j]<-'1'
            if(temp$setpoint[i+j] != (temp$setpoint[i+j+1])){break}
          }
        }
```

**break HERE!** otherwise the inner loop might rerun times doing the exactly same!

```
      }
    }
  }
}
```